# Launching Camera Intent on AVD throwing IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera

I'm attempting to create a temp file to store an image from the camera intent, following the [Android Photo Basics](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) guide, but every time I try to create one from my android emulator, it's crashing. It works fine from my physical Nexus 7, so I know it's not a permissions issue.

I set a breakpoint and followed it down, and it's going into the BlockGuardOs, and after a little research it sounds like that's a way to ensure you're following proper thread control, so I attempted to move my code into an `AsyncTask`, but it's still crashing with the same error.

The original method I was using:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );

    return image;
}
```

After that I moved it into an `AsyncTask`

```
class CreateImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {
    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = null;

        try {
            File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }

        return image;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            if (file != null) {
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_RESP);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm still running into the same issue. I know I can disable this by changing the StrictThread settings, but I'd like some advice on how I can handle the file IO off the main UI thread.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure tah you add the right permissions in app manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
To access the device camera, you must declare the CAMERA permission in your Android Manifest. Also be sure to include the <uses-feature> manifest element to declare camera features used by your application. For example, if you use the camera and auto-focus feature, your Manifest should include the following:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the correct permissions, and it works with my physical tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't define camera for you emulator .
if you are using android studio do this :

> 1.open **AVD manager**
>
> 2.Under Actions column choose **edit AVD** ( pen icon )
>
> 3.Click **SHOW ADVANCED SETTING**
>
> 4.At camera select your **back** and **front** camera
>
> 5.Finish

Comment: They're both emulated, and they work fine with the included camera app